# roll until lose game with changing probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

- Start with probability `p` $= 1$
- Keep rolling until you get a failure.
- Modify `p` after each roll, multiplying it by `k`
- Count the number of successes.

```
    event_count = 0
    p = 1
    while random() < p:
        event_count += 1
        p *= k
```

$E$ = expected value of `event_count` at the end

I'm looking for a formula for `k` in terms of $E$.

(This would be the inversion of the function for $E$, given `k`.)

---

`random()` gives a continuous uniform distribution $[0, 1)$

The probability `p` changes at each iteration (multiplied by `k`).

`event_count` will always be at least $1$, since `p` starts at $1$, so the first random roll will always be a success.

---

If `k` $>= 1$, `event_count` is infinity.

If `k` $<= 0$, `event_count` is $1$.

So the interesting values of `k` are $(0, 1)$

---

Some samples give these numbers:

```
            E: k
            1.0: 0.0,
            1.01: 0.01,
            1.1: 0.099,
            1.25: 0.238,
            1.5: 0.42,
            2.0: 0.645,
            3.0: 0.833,
            4.0: 0.904,
            5.0: 0.938,
            6.0: 0.957,
            7.0: 0.9685,
```

Most of these digits are significant.

I found $0.968$ to be pretty reliably giving $E < 7$ and $0.969$ to reliably give $E > 7$

---

What's the formula to relate $E$ and `k`?

Comment: My *guess* is that you're looking at successive terms of a geometric series (ie, adding the first n elements of a geometric series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E=1(1-k)+2k(1-k^2)+3k(k^2)(1-k^3)+4k(k^2)(k^3)(1-k^4)+\cdots$$
$$=1(k^0-k^1)+2(k^1-k^3)+3(k^3-k^6)+4(k^6-k^{10})+\cdots$$
$$=k^0+k^1+k^3+k^6+\cdots$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty k^{n(n+1)/2}=\frac{\vartheta_2(\sqrt k)}{2k^{1/8}}$$
where $\vartheta_2$ is the Jacobi theta function of the second kind. There is no closed-form inverse to this relation, but $E=7$ at $k=0.96819950284\dots$

Comment: Hmmm... But what I care about is something that tells me k, given E as the input.

Comment: @beauxq You're going to have to invert the equation numerically – there's no other way. The function of $E$ given $k$ is strictly monotonically increasing though, so numerical inversion should be easy.